# Error in installing matplotlib to pandas on windows via cmd

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, anaconda, powerbi

I want to run Python in Power BI. For this I need to install pandas and matplotlib.
Installing Pandas was no problem via the cmd and typing "py -m pip install pandas"
The same did not work with installing matplotlib.

The error in Power BI is the following:

```
DataSource.Error: ADO.NET: ΡУţћõη §ċѓίρт єґŕōŗ.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PythonScriptWrapper.PY", line 2, in <module>
    import os, pandas, matplotlib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

Details:
    DataSourceKind=Python
    DataSourcePath=Python
    Message=ΡУţћõη §ċѓίρт єґŕōŗ.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PythonScriptWrapper.PY", line 2, in <module>
    import os, pandas, matplotlib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

    ErrorCode=-2147467259
    ExceptionType=Microsoft.PowerBI.Scripting.Python.Exceptions.PythonScriptRuntimeException
```

So thats why need to install matplotlib.

This ist the error I get in cmd after trying to install matplotlib:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\user\\btues\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ve_4eeff\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ve_4eeff\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-gql4w5zw\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Does anyone knows this error, have experienced something similar and can help me out?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you set the options path in Power BI to use the correct Anaconda env folder?

Comment: Yes, I have one folder for anaconda and one for python, tried both

Comment: Anaconda won't work unless you activate at least the base environment before starting PBIDesktop.exe.